# How to use ListView in Asp.net WebForm

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this code and i can only display it in a textbox

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string connect =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TDBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    string query = "SELECT news, news_date FROM [IBSI].[dbo].[ibsi.news]";

    if (query != null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
             {

              conn.Open();
              SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              if (rdr.HasRows)
              {
                   while (rdr.Read())
                   {
                      Textbox1.Text=rdr["news"].ToString();
                   }
              }
         }
    }
}
else 
{
      Response.Write("<p>No customer selected</p>"); 
}

}
</script
```

and i only display it here

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="168px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                        Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>
```

But in my database i have more than 1 data so i need a listview to display this items.
Please help me on how to do that.

Comment: classic-asp is not asp.net. Tag removed.

Comment: First off, place the code in your code-behind file. Also, get the data on the first page only (!Page.IsPostBack)... the way you have it set up it's going to hit the DB on each postback from the form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sample HTML for Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="header" style="background:green;" runat="server">
                    textBox
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ed" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("news") %>' autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

### Sample Code

```
public class News
{
    public String news;
}
List<News> Listnews = new List<News>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Listnews.Add(new News { news = rdr["news"].ToString() });
            }
        }
    }
}

rpt.DataSource = Listnews;
rpt.DataBind();
```